# Swift weak delegate

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, delegates

my code:

```
public func start() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    guard let listVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListVC") as? ListVC else { return }
    let viewModel = ListViewModel(dependencies: appDependencies)
    viewModel.delegate = self
    listVC.listViewModel = viewModel

    navigationController?.pushViewController(listVC, animated: true)
}


protocol ListViewModelDelegate: class {
    func needChangeScreen(cellViewModel: UserCellViewModel)
}

final class ListViewModel {

  weak var delegate: ListViewModelDelegate?

    func userPressed(at index: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.needChangeScreen(cellViewModel: cellViewModels[index.row])
    }
}
```

User pressed is called from UIViewController , then i want to send callback to Coordinator to start another coordinator but delegate? is always nil. I know that delegates should be weak but in this case is not working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: How is `start` called?  It seems likely that the instance of `ListVC` that is active didn't come from `start`

Comment: Make sure something is holding a reference to your coordinator object too.  If the only thing referencing it is the view controller delegate which is `weak` then it will be deallocated after the `start` function runs which would make the delegate nil.

Answer (score 0):

Okey i have fix but i do not know is it good.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let navigationController = UINavigationController()
    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    let appDependencies = configureAppDependencies()
    let coordinator = AppCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController, appDependencies: appDependencies)
    coordinator.start()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

That was my app delegate function(In AppCoordinator start is created and pushed ListCoordinator) but when i changed let coordinator for instance var :

```
var coordinator: AppCoordinator?
```

weak delegate is not nil and everything works.